# Assistance with Wordpress Usermeta MySQL Querying

Tags: mysql, sql-server, wordpress, subquery

I am trying to write a few queries that I will setup as views after I finish them. I have a WordPress site with paid subscribers, who also receive a magazine monthly.

I need to be able to query the database by `Subscription Expiration date`, i.e. find subscribers whose subscription ends in the current month & year. The issue is that the subscription expiration date is stored in the WordPress user metadata table of `wp_usermeta`, and is stored as a string.

So far I have:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'subscriber_id' THEN m.meta_value END) as Subscriber_ID,
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'subscription_exp' THEN m.meta_value END) as 'Subscription Expiration',
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'first_name' THEN m.meta_value END) as First_Name,
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'last_name' THEN m.meta_value END) as Last_Name,
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'billing_address_1' THEN m.meta_value END) as Address_1,
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'billing_city' THEN m.meta_value END) as City,
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'billing_state' THEN m.meta_value END) as State,
  MAX(CASE m.meta_key WHEN 'billing_postalcode' THEN m.meta_value END) as Postal_Code
FROM wp_usermeta m
GROUP BY m.user_id
```

This gives me ALL of the subscribers, regardless of expiration in the following format:

```
Subscriber_ID | Subscription Expiration | Etc...
------------------------------------------------
59599482      | 1/9/2017                | etc..
```

*I didn't include the query additions for any of my attempts to figure this out for purposes of avoiding confusion*

Now, I know I can convert the string to a `timestamp/date` via `STR_TO_DATE`, but I couldn't seem to figure out how to filter by month/year. 
If I were using PostgreSQL, I would write a subquery to grab the `subscription_exp` and then convert it using `STR_TO_DATE`, then reference it in the `outerquery` and filter using `WHERE MONTH(subquery.subscription_exp) = 4 AND YEAR (subquery.subscription_exp) = 2017`.

I just couldn't figure out for the life of me how to accomplish this in MySQL. Any assistance is appreciated.

It's my first time posting to Stackoverflow, but have come here countless times to find solutions to problems i've come accross.

Thanks!